# SLDS Grid Columns Not the Same Width

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, slds, slds-grid

I'm creating a form and using `lightning:layout` and giving the `lightning:layoutItem` a size of 4, which renders `<div class="slds-size_4-of-12">`. However, I noticed that the last column in the grid is slightly wider than the others, even though all divs have a class of `slds-size_4-of-12`

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the Lightning markup:

```
<div class="slds-p-bottom_small">
    <lightning:layout>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
            <lightning:input aura:id="firstName" label="First name" name="firstName" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
            <lightning:input aura:id="middleInitial" label="Middle initial" name="middleInitial" maxlength="2" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layoutItem size="4">
            <lightning:input aura:id="lastName" label="Last name" name="lastName" />
        </lightning:layoutItem>
    </lightning:layout>
</div>
```

Do you know why that is, and how can I get all columns to be equal width?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: The code outputs equal widths, can you share the code that is behind the screenshot?